# How to display two different table mismatch record?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT d.c_id,  
       d.total_amt,
       d.date AS pay_detail_dish, 
       w.amount, 
       w.date AS pay_detail_dishweb 
FROM  pay_detail_dish d, pay_detail_dishweb w 
//WHERE d.c_id = w.c_id
```

Above code are display all record but mismatch record not display in mysql

Comment: What your exact problem I cant understand your question please explain properly

Comment: Define what Mismatched records

Comment: c_id     total_amt     date            c_id1  amount  date1        Diff
1594096  10300  02-Nov-16   1594096  10300  03-Nov-16      0
1530943  1030  02-Nov-16   1530943  1030    03-Nov-16      0 
1440436  10300  03-Nov-16   1440436  10300  03-Nov-16      0
1325129  3090  02-Nov-16   1325129  3090    03-Nov-16      0
1233763  2060  02-Nov-16   1233763  2060    03-Nov-16      0 
1194883  4120  03-Nov-16    null            null   null          -4120

i need this out put but it not like this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN` , so you have to `LEFT JOIN` -> `UNION` -> `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT d.c_id,  
   d.total_amt,
   d.date AS pay_detail_dish, 
   w.amount, 
   w.date AS pay_detail_dishweb 
FROM  pay_detail_dish d
LEFT JOIN pay_detail_dishweb w ON d.c_id = w.c_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT s.c_id,  
   s.total_amt,
   s.date AS pay_detail_dish, 
   p.amount, 
   p.date AS pay_detail_dishweb 
FROM  pay_detail_dish s
RIGHT JOIN pay_detail_dishweb p ON s.c_id = p.c_id 
WHERE s.c_id is null
```

Comment: above statement i got this  1054 - Unknown column 'd.c_id' in 'field list'

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 's.total_amt' in 'field list' now this

Comment: result remain 0 in php

Comment: What does remain 0 means?

Comment: $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn)or die (mysql_error());    
           
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                   {
 $total_amt= $row[pay_detail_dish.total_amt]; 
                  $amount=$row[pay_detail_dishweb.amount] ;

$diff=amount-$total_amt;